# OpenGL: draw 2 cylinder

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw two cylinder, both filled with the same texture, but I have managed to draw only the first one, here is my draw func:

```
void display(void)
{
    // Projection plane
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //a->draw(mouseY);
    //draw first cylinder WORKING
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(mouseY, 0, 0, 1); 
        quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH);
        gluQuadricTexture(quadratic, GL_TRUE);
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(90,0,0,1);
            glTranslatef(0,-1.0,0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        gluCylinder(quadratic,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);
        if(!exec) //used only one time to get a visible cylinder
        {
            glTranslatef(fX_cylpos,fY_cylpos,0);
            glRotatef(90, 0.0, 1, 0.0); //rotate object 90° on Y axis
            glRotatef(fangle_cyl, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //0° = vertical / 90° = horizontal
            exec=true;
        }
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        //draw second cylinder NOT WORKING
        glRotatef(mouseY, 0, 0, 1);
        quadratic2 = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricNormals(quadratic2, GLU_SMOOTH);
        gluQuadricTexture(quadratic2, GL_TRUE);
        gluCylinder(quadratic2,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);
        if(!exec2) 
        {
            glTranslatef(fX_cylpos+200,fY_cylpos,0);
            glRotatef(90, 0.0, 1, 0.0); //rotate object 90° on Y axis
            glRotatef(fangle_cyl, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);  //0° = vertical / 90° = horizontal      
            exec2=true;
        }
    glPopMatrix();
   //b->draw(mouseY);
   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

And this is the reshape func:

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   //glOrtho(-1000.0, 1000.0*(screen_h/screen_w), -1000.0, 1000.0*(screen_h/screen_w), 1000.0, -110.0);
   glOrtho(fOrtoXinit, fOrtoXend, fOrtoYinit, fOrtoYend , 1000, -1000.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

The code in the `if` statement is used to draw the cylinder vertical, as in picture below and than it is rotated with the mouse along x axis to scroll the numbers :[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ou5z.png)

Thanks to Reto Koradi's reply I've managed to draw 2 cylinder meanwhile I still have two problems:
1. I don't know what I have to change to put a cylinder next to the other;
2. I think that my solution to draw a vertical cylinder using `if` statement is not a good way...

Here is the edited code:

```
if(!exec) //basically IF is not used anymore
{
    glTranslatef(fX_cylpos,fY_cylpos,0);
    glRotatef(90, 0.0, 1, 0.0); //rotate object 90° on Y axis
    glRotatef(fangle_cyl, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //0° = vertical / 90° = horizontal
    //exec=true;
}
gluCylinder(quadratic,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);            
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
//draw second cylinder NOT WORKING
glRotatef(mouseY, 0, 0, 1);
quadratic2 = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricNormals(quadratic2, GLU_SMOOTH);
gluQuadricTexture(quadratic2, GL_TRUE);
if(!exec2) 
{
    glTranslatef(fX_cylpos+200,fY_cylpos,20);
    glRotatef(90, 0.0, 1, 0.0); //rotate object 90° on Y axis
    glRotatef(fangle_cyl, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);  //0° = vertical / 90° = horizontal      
    exec2=true;
}
gluCylinder(quadratic2,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);

glPopMatrix();
```

This is the result after moving cylinders a bit with the mouse
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXeIn.png)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you're drawing two cylinders with exactly the same transformations and dimensions. Why do you expect to see two different cylinders if you draw the same thing twice?

Comment: I use a gltranslatef with different x position for the second one and if I disable the first one the second is drawn exactly where I want...

Comment: The only `glTranslatef()` calls in this code  are either applied in `GL_TEXTURE` matrix mode, or after a draw call. So none of them influence the position of the cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this typo?

```
    gluQuadricTexture(quadratic2, GL_TRUE);
    gluCylinder(quadratic,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);
```

->

```
    gluQuadricTexture(quadratic2, GL_TRUE);
    gluCylinder(quadratic2,fh_cyl,fh_cyl,fw_cyl,50,1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but yeah, it's only a typo, and even fixing it doesn't give a visible change